# I need to filter 2 conditions from the same column in PIG HADOOP

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am new to pig.

What am I trying to achieve is getting 2 values from 1 table and find if a certain id has both of these items.

For example

Product Table

| **Product Name** |
| --- |
| Tofu |
| Ikura |
| Sushi |

Order table

| Order ID | Product Name |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Ikura |
| 124 | Ikura |
| 124 | Tofu |
| 125 | Sushi |
| 126 | Tofu |
| 127 | Tofu |

What I want to achieve is
| Order ID | Product Name |
|:---:|:--:|
|124|Ikura|
|124|Tofu|

I want to find all the orderID with both Ikura and Tofu.

What I've tried so far is:

```
fil = FILTER productTbl BY PRODUCT_NAME IN ('Ikura', 'Tofu');

joinTable = join order_detailTbl by PRODUCT_ID, fil by PRODUCT_ID;

generateID = foreach joinTable generate ORDER_ID;
```

In which it gives me the output of all order id that has either Ikura or Tofu. But the condition is having both in 1 order ID.

I've tried all sorts of ways and I have no idea how to do it... Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `OR`

```
fil = FILTER productTbl BY (PRODUCT_NAME = 'Ikura' OR PRODUCT_NAME = 'Tofu');
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the orders that contain **both** 'Ikura' and 'Tofu', you will need to group the data by the order ID. Then, filter the bags to those that contain both of these values. Finally, filter the data for non-empty bags.

```
grp = GROUP productTbl BY ORDER_ID;

ikuraTofuIds = FOREACH grp {
    ikuras = FILTER productTbl BY PRODUCT_NAME == 'Ikura';
    tofus = FILTER productTbl BY PRODUCT_NAME == 'Tofu';
    GENERATE group AS ORDER_ID,
    ikuras,
    tofus;
}

ikuraTofuOrders = FILTER ikuraTofuIds BY NOT IsEmpty(ikuras) AND NOT IsEmpty(tofus);

finalOrders = FOREACH ikuraTofuOrders GENERATE ORDER_ID;
```